# Python Pandas: Overwriting an Index with a list of datetime objects

Tags: python, datetime, indexing, pandas

I have an input CSV with timestamps in the header like this (the number of timestamps forming columns is several thousand):

> header1;header2;header3;header4;header5;2013-12-30CET00:00:00;2013-12-30CET00:01:00;...;2014-00-01CET00:00:00

In Pandas 0.12 I was able to do this, to convert string timestamps into datetime objects. The following code strips out the 'CEST' in the timestamp string (`translate()`), reads it in as a datetime (`strptime()`) and then localizes it to the correct timezone (`localize()`) [The reason for this approach was because, with the versions I had at least, CEST wasn't being recognised as a timezone].

```
DF = pd.read_csv('some_csv.csv',sep=';')
transtable = string.maketrans(string.uppercase,' '*len(string.uppercase))
tz = pytz.country_timezones('nl')[0]
timestamps = DF.columns[5:]
timestamps = map(lambda x:x.translate(transtable), timestamps)
timestamps = map(lambda x:datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), timestamps)
timestamps = map(lambda x: pytz.timezone(tz).localize(x), timestamps)
DF.columns[5:] = timestamps
```

However, my downstream code required that I run off of pandas 0.16
While running on 0.16, I get this error with the above code at the last line of the above snippet:

> *** TypeError: Indexes does not support mutable operations

I'm looking for a way to overwrite my index with the datetime object. Using the method `to_datetime()` doesn't work for me, returning:

> *** ValueError: Unknown string format

I have some subsequent code that copies, then drops, the first few columns of data in this dataframe (all the 'header1; header2, header3'leaving just the timestamps. The purpose being to then transpose, and index by the timestamp.

So, my question:

Either: 
how can I overwrite a series of column names with a datetime, such that I can pass in a pre-arranged set of timestamps that pandas will be able to recognise as a timestamp in subsequent code (in pandas v0.16)
Or:
Any other suggestions that achieve the same effect.

I've explored `set_index()`, `replace()`, `to_datetime()` and `reindex()` and possibly some others but non seem to be able to achieve this overwrite. Hopefully this is simple to do, and I'm just missing something.

TIA

Comment: Would be nice to have the first few rows and cols of the csv (so we can try out the code ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this by the following:

The issue was that I had several thousand column headers with timestamps, that I couldn't directly parse into datetime objects.

So, in order to get these timestamp objects incorporated I added a new column called 'Time', and then included the datetime objects in there, then setting the index to the new column (I'm omitting code where I purged the rows of other header data, through `drop()` methods:

```
    DF = DF.transpose()  
    DF['Time'] = timestamps 
    DF = DF.set_index('Time')
```

Summary: If you have a CSV with a set of timestamps in your headers that you cannot parse; a way around this is to parse them separately, include in a new column of Time with the correct datetime objects, then `set_index()` based on the new column.